# Question about helicoid and helix

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, curves

I would like to know, if I have this as the parameterization of a helicoid

$H(r, \phi):=\begin{pmatrix} r\cos \phi \\ r \sin\phi \\ \phi\end{pmatrix}$, $r \in[-1,1], \phi \in [0,2\pi] $

what would the boundary of the helicoid be? In my opinion it should be a helix, I have found something here
https://mathinsight.org/parametrized_surface_introduction. would the boundary just be in case of **r** fixed, once with $1$ and once with $-1$? or how could I determine the boundary of the given parameterization?

Comment: My question is whether "helicoid" is a correct spelling.  I have hardly ever seen a soft "c" before an "o".

Comment: @OscarLanzi: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicoid I don't think that it is with a soft c, pretty sure it is with a hard c. :)